# Fish - A way to configure it such that it does not scroll through tab completions with tab

Tags: command-line, terminal, autocomplete, fish

If you have a directory structure like the below

```
./test/locationOne
./test/locationTwo
./test/locationThree
```

If, with bash, or fish, you type in

```
cd test/
```

then hit tab, it will autocomplete until test/location. In bash, if you hit tab again, it does the same autocomplete. However, with fish, it starts to scroll through the options. ie. Hit tab once more, and it selects ./test/locationOne, once more goes to locationTwo, etc. I find this quite difficult to work with and I'd like to disable it.

Is it possible?